# How to check if a user/session is using a package ?

Tags: oracle, session, oracle11g, oracle10g, package

I have a package `ARG_AP_INVOCE_PKG` which has went to **INVAILD** status.
After compilation it has not went to VAILD status.

So I cross checked with my developers and found out one of them was developing on it.

In such case how to find which package is being used by another user/session ?

Please provide me query for this.

Thanks!

Comment: What you are looking for is compilation history. I do not think its possible

Comment: No @PraneethGudumasu ...
One of the developer is working on the package, so it got INVAILD.
In the meanwhile I want to check which user/session is using the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query v$locked_object e.g.

```
select  /*+ RULE */
  s.sid,
  s.serial#,
  p.spid "OS SID",
  s.sql_hash_value "HASH VALUE",
  s.username "ORA USER",
  s.status,
  s.osuser "OS USER",
  s.machine,
  s.terminal,
  s.type,
  s.program,
  s.logon_time,
  s.last_call_et,
  s.sql_id,
  l.process,
  decode(L.locked_mode,1,'No Lock', 
                2,'Row Share', 
                3,'Row Exclusive', 
                4,'Share', 
                5,'Share Row Exclusive', 
                6,'Exclusive','NONE') "Lock Mode",
  o.OWNER,
  o.OBJECT_NAME,
  o.OBJECT_TYPE    
from 
  v$session s,v$locked_object l, dba_objects o, v$process p
where 
  p.addr = s.paddr and
  s.sid=l.session_id and
  l.object_id=o.object_id
order by sid
```

or this will find all objects being accessed in cursors if there are no locks

```
select  /*+ RULE */
  s.sid,
  s.serial#,
  p.spid "OS SID",
  s.sql_hash_value "HASH VALUE",
  s.username "ORA USER",
  s.status,
  s.osuser "OS USER",
  s.machine,
  s.terminal,
  s.type,
  s.program,
  s.logon_time,
  s.sql_id,
  a.owner,
  a.object,
  a.type "OBJ TYPE"
from 
  v$session s,v$process p, v$access a
where 
  p.addr = s.paddr and
  a.sid=s.sid
order by sid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `V$SESSION` and find `id` and `instance` to detect who block you

> check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_3016.htm#REFRN30223)

Comment: Yes I can get the user who has logged into the machine with user ID.
But I want to know what data object they are accessing ?